# How to hide wordpress error message?

Tags: permissions

how to hide wordpress error message "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" and show 404 error page for all non administrator's request like e.g mydomain.com/wp-admin/plugin.php and all such requests. And they should be redirected to 404 error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "redirect".

If you want to 404 them, this will do the job:

```
add_filter('wp_die_handler','custom_404_die_handler');
function custom_404_die_handler() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->handle_404();
    load_template(get_404_template());
    die();
}
```

If you actually want to redirect them somewhere, then you could do something like this, but that's not exactly a "404", as such.

```
add_filter('wp_die_handler','custom_404_die_handler');
function custom_404_die_handler() {
    wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help can you please tell me where to put that code because I am a newbie.

Comment: Great it worked I put that in the theme's function.php and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: how to redirect them to the current page or post.

Comment: If they're going to an admin page, then there really isn't any "current page or post" to redirect them to.